# Некорректное отображение формы Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема такая: после изменения размера формы и добавления пары элементов при запуске программы форма отображается меньше, чем нужно. Свойство `FormBorderStyle` установлено `FixedDialog`. Окно отображается нужного размера, если установить его в `Sizable`. После поисков обнаружил, что в `Designer.cs` свойство `ClientSize` устанавливает размер меньше, когда изменил его на нужный `(371, 256)`, окно стало правильного размера, но при этом в свойстве `Size` значения стали больше `(389, 303)` и в дизайнере форма стала большего размера, чем нужно. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Size` - размер с бордюром, `ClientSize` - без бордюра.

Comment: Если чуть точнее, то Size - внешний размер формы, включая шапку и бордер, размер которых зависит от стиля оформления самой формы и стиля оформления ОС (Aero например). ClientSize - размер области, в которой рисуются дочерние контролы и прочий контент формы. Эти размеры всегда различаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я заметил, что Visual Studio страдает болезнью иногда рандомно менять что-то в файле `Designer.cs`. Решение оказалось следующим: открыл тот же файл из старой версии программы и заменил строчку с  `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F)` на `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F)`, после чего все стало на места.